# mongo lookup aggregation overwrite the whole object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

im trying to populate added_by field that exist in the actions array  inside  claim object
here is an exemple:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('.....'),
        actions: [
            {

                added_by: ObjectId('64d4f8a3fd3df..'),
                message: 'test'
            },
            {

                added_by: ObjectId('64d4f8a3fd3....'),
                message: 'test2'
            },
            //rest of records
        ]
}
```

what i would like to achieve is this :

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('.....'),
        actions: [
            {
                added_by: {

                    "email": "test@gmail.com",
                    // rest of properties
                }
                message: 'test'
            },
            {

                added_by: added_by: {
                "email": "testf@gmail.com",
                // rest of properties
            },
                message: 'test2'
                },
                 //rest of records
]
        }
```

i tried  to do it this way :

```
lookup.push({
      $lookup: {
        from: 'users', // The collection you are performing the lookup on (users collection)
        let: { actions: '$actions' }, // Variable for matching IDs
        as: 'actions', // The field to store the populated results
        pipeline: [
          {
            $match: {
              $expr: {
                $in: ['$_id', '$$actions.added_by'], // Match users whose '_id' is in the 'added_by' array
              },
            },
          },
        
         
        ],
      },
    });
```

but  it has   many issues
1 -  it overwrites  the whole object so it will be something like this  ( message field will be deleted
2- if 2 actions for exemple are created by same user  on the output    i find a  1 user  only  instead of  outputting same  user twice

any idea how to fix it ?

```
{
        _id: ObjectId('.....'),
            actions: [
                {
                    added_by: {
    
                        "email": "test@gmail.com",
                        // rest of properties
                    }
                    
                },
                {
    
                    added_by: added_by: {
                    "email": "testf@gmail.com",
                    // rest of properties
                },
                  
                    },
                     //rest of records
    ]
            }
```

here is a full exemple
claim document :

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('64d79a9b5239b08bb7c00bb0'),
    claim_message: 'hola',
    files: [],
    added_by: ObjectId('64d4f8a3fd3dfa4fd2a37607'),
    company: ObjectId('64d4b30dfd3dfa4fd2a37283'),
    services: [
        ObjectId('64d4b0f4fd3dfa4fd2a3720f')
    ],
    status: 'open',
    createdAt: ISODate('2023-08-12T14:43:39.343Z'),
    updatedAt: ISODate('2023-08-12T18:57:40.162Z'),
    actions: [
        {
            files: null,
            added_by: ObjectId('64d4f8a3fd3dfa4fd2a37607'),
            message: 'testing'
        },
        {
            files: null,
            added_by: ObjectId('64d4f8a3fd3dfa4fd2a37607'),
            message: 'new reply'
        },
        {
            files: null,
            added_by: ObjectId('64d4f8a3fd3dfa4fd2a37879'),
            message: 'another reply'
        },


    ]
}
```

user collection

```
{
    {
        _id: ObjectId('64d4f8a3fd3dfa4fd2a37607'),
        account_type: 'CLIENT',
        email: 'linked@gmail.com',
        
    },
    {
        _id: ObjectId('64d4f8a3fd3dfa4fd2a37879'),
        account_type: 'CLIENT',
        email: 'visitor@gmail.com',
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide sample documents which demonstrate both problems, and the requested results.

Comment: Your result is invalid. The second object in `actions` array,  you need to wrap the value for the first `added_by` with curly braces. While why the second object should have nested `added_by` but first object didn't have nested object for `added_by`.

Comment: i included  a full working  exemple  in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is:

1. Assign the `$lookup` result to a temp field instead of the original field
2. Use `$map` with `$mergeObjects` to merge and `$arrayElemAt` with `$indexOfArray` to match the items

```
db.claims.aggregate([
  {$lookup: {
      from: "users",
      let: {actions: "$actions"},
      as: "actionUsers",
      pipeline: [
        {$match: {$expr: {$in: ["$_id", "$$actions.added_by"]}}}
      ]
  }},
  {$set: {
      actions: {$map: {
          input: "$actions",
          in: {$mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {$arrayElemAt: [
                  "$actionUsers",
                  {$indexOfArray: ["$actionUsers._id", "$$this.added_by"]}
              ]}
          ]}
      }},
      actionUsers: "$$REMOVE"
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yuanR3UM9wG)